# How can I run jQuery in AngularJs outside of a controller and inside a view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pug

I am building a code snippet library of sorts on top of an angular seed and compiling using Jade/Gulp. The goal is to have various categories/pages of collections of working/live examples of reusable code on a given page, where the user is also able to copy the relevant scss, jade, html, etc. to be used in other projects (almost identical to the Bourbon Refills site - http://refills.bourbon.io/)

I am using a jade mixin to render each snippet on the category pages.

```
mixin snippet(category, title, url)
.snippet-container

    // Title of Snippet

    // Snippet Markup (HTML)

    .snippet-markup(ng-include="'app/snippets/#{category}/#{url}/markup.html'")

// Snippet Copy Table / Raw Resources

.refill-snippet
    .refill-control
        a.snippet-link-toggle(ng-click="showSnippet-!{url}=true" ng-hide="showSnippet-!{url}") Show Code
        a.snippet-link-toggle(ng-click="showSnippet-!{url}=false" ng-show="showSnippet-!{url}") Hide Code
    table.snippets-table(ng-show="showSnippet-!{url}")
        tbody
            tr
                // Markup Column HTML / Jade
                td.snippet
                    .copy-source-container
                        a.copy-source(ngclipboard='', data-clipboard-target='#jade') Copy Jade
                    pre.language-markup
                        code#jade.language-jade(prism ng-include="'master/snippets/#{category}/#{url}/_jade.html'")

                // Styles Column SCSS,SASS/LESS/CSS
                td.snippet
                    .copy-source-container
                        a.copy-source(ngclipboard='', data-clipboard-target='#scss') Copy Scss
                    pre.language-markup
                        code#scss.language-sass(prism ng-include="'master/snippets/#{category}/#{url}/_scss.scss'")

                // Scripts Column Javascript, jQuery, CoffeeScript
                td.snippet
                    .copy-source-container
                        a.copy-source(ngclipboard='', data-clipboard-target='#js-1') Copy JavaScript
                    pre.language-markup
                        code#js-1.language-javascript(prism ng-include="'master/snippets/#{category}/#{url}/_js.js'")
```

And then referencing each snippet on a given category view as such:

```
include mixins
```

section

```
// Tabs 1
+snippet('accordions-tabs', 'Accordions 1', 'tabs-1')
// Tabs 2
+snippet('accordions-tabs', 'Accordions 2', 'tabs-2')
```

The problem/hurdle i am trying to overcome is getting the javascript/jQuery required for each snippet to run on the page. Is there a way i can include all of the JS required for the snippets in one included .js file and have it work within my angular app? (I have tried this, but to no avail). Or Am i limited to running javascript/jQuery from within a controller only and i need to find someway to pass the JS from a template/view into a controller?

Here is an example of the markup for a snippet:

```
<ul class="accordion-tabs">
<li class="tab-header-and-content"></li>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="is-active tab-link">Tab Item</a>
<div class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tincidunt pellentesque lorem, id suscipit
        dolor rutrum id. Morbi facilisis porta volutpat. Fusce adipiscing, mauris quis congue tincidunt, sapien
        purus
        suscipit odio, quis dictum
        odio tortor in sem. Ut sit amet libero nec orci mattis fringilla. Praesent eu ipsum in sapien tincidunt
        molestie
        sed ut magna. Nam accumsan dui at orci rhoncus pharetra tincidunt elit ullamcorper. Sed ac mauris ipsum.
        Nullam
        imperdiet sapien id
        purus pretium id aliquam mi ullamcorper.</p>
</div>
<li class="tab-header-and-content"></li>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tab-link">Another Tab</a>
<div class="tab-content">
    <p>Ut laoreet augue et neque pretium non sagittis nibh pulvinar. Etiam ornare tincidunt orci quis ultrices.
        Pellentesque ac sapien ac purus gravida ullamcorper. Duis rhoncus sodales lacus, vitae adipiscing tellus
        pharetra sed. Praesent bibendum
        lacus quis metus condimentum ac accumsan orci vulputate. Aenean fringilla massa vitae metus facilisis
        congue. Morbi placerat eros ac sapien semper pulvinar. Vestibulum facilisis, ligula a molestie venenatis,
        metus justo ullamcorper ipsum, congue
        aliquet dolor tortor eu neque. Sed imperdiet, nibh ut vestibulum tempor, nibh dui volutpat lacus, vel
        gravida magna justo sit amet quam. Quisque tincidunt ligula at nisl imperdiet sagittis. Morbi rutrum tempor
        arcu, non ultrices sem semper a. Aliquam
        quis sem mi.</p>
</div>
<li class="tab-header-and-content"></li>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tab-link">Third</a>
<div class="tab-content">
    <p>Donec mattis mauris gravida metus laoreet non rutrum sem viverra. Aenean nibh libero, viverra vel vestibulum
        in, porttitor ut sapien. Phasellus tempor lorem id justo ornare tincidunt. Nulla faucibus, purus eu placerat
        fermentum, velit mi iaculis
        nunc, bibendum tincidunt ipsum justo eu mauris. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum vel lectus ac purus tempus
        suscipit nec sit amet eros. Nullam fringilla, enim eu lobortis dapibus, quam magna tincidunt nibh, sit amet
        imperdiet dolor justo congue turpis.</p></div>
<li class="tab-header-and-content"></li>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tab-link">Last Item</a>
<div class="tab-content">
    <p>Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus dui urna...</p>
</div>
```

And the required jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.accordion-tabs').each(function (index) {
    $(this).children('li').first().children('a').addClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-open').show();
});
$('.accordion-tabs').on('click', 'li > a.tab-link', function (event) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var accordionTabs = $(this).closest('.accordion-tabs');
        accordionTabs.find('.is-open').removeClass('is-open').hide();

        $(this).next().toggleClass('is-open').toggle();
        accordionTabs.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

});

Import note - I can make the JS work for the snippet by manually placing it in the controller and modify all jQuery selectors to angular selectors, but that defeats the purpose of this snippet library as not ALL projects will be run in an angular app.

Any insight on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not clear at all how any of this ties into angular.

Comment: It's just being built on top of angular, i guess i could include my index file, but not sure what else angular-wise to include that would help.

Comment: Point is it's not clear how any of the html for your snippets is inserted in DOM. *"Built on top of angular"* is somewhat meaningless ....  and usually a recipe for major problems. As for putting code in controller that is definitely not right ... the norm would be use directives

Answer (score 0):

In principle it is easy, you can just assign `angular.element` to a global `$` and that's all you need:

```
window.$ = angular.element;
$('#somediv').html('<p>ipsum lorem</p>');
```

However, Angular contains only a severely neutered version of jQuery called jqLite, and this will not work with your code as it does not support (amongst other things) selection via query selectors. The code above will only throw:

> Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/jqLite/nosel

on the browser Javascript console. There is a `$(document).ready()` however, and you can use it.

To illustrate, I have put together a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qarodeqoti/edit?html,js,console) example that has two `<div>`, one is bound by Angular, one would be filled by jQuery (that never happens because of the ["nosel" no selector error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/jqLite/nosel) ).

The `$(document).ready()` logs to the console, so you can see it is supported.

Now, typically, I use the full jQuery from a CDN alongside Angular in my projects. For most visitors, this is a HTTP status `304` and it is way more useful than jqLite, even though I try not to manipulate the DOM myself.

Comment: What does any of this have to do with OP running the code shown in question? Presumably jQuery is already included in page or there would have been `$ not defined` error

Comment: I tried assigning the angular.element to the global '$', but that didn't do it. Thanks for the tip on using a full version of jQuery as i wasn't previously.

Comment: using the following code snippet works in a separate javascript file:
`angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        alert('You clicked a tab!');
});`

But using:
`angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    window.$ = angular.element;
    $('.tab-link').click(function(){
        alert('You clicked a tab!');
    });
});`
Does NOT work..

Comment: Yes, as I wrote above: "Angular contains only a severely neutered version of jQuery called jqLite, and this will not work with your code as it does not support (amongst other things) **selection via query selectors**". The easiest way to get `$('.tab-link').click()` to work is via a full jQuery.

Comment: Yes, i have included a full version of jQuery and it is still not working as intended.

Comment: But you have removed the `window.$ = angular.element; ` line if you include a full jQuery, right? Because in that line, you'd overwrite it with jqLite.

Answer (score -1):

I did a mix of the two and the only requirement was to load the scripts in this order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">//jQuery</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jQuery.js">//Flow and animations my script</script>
<script src="script/lib/angular.min.js">//AngularJS</script>
<script src="script/lib/angular-fullscreen.js">//AngularJS-fullscreen</script>
<script src="script/menuContent.js">//...Controller_for_AngularJS</script>
```

all interaction between angular and jQuery is done true the document DOM state (the view states ;))

Comment: Ive tried playing around with the load order of angular and jQuery-related elements (jquery first before angular/angular-based scripts), no dice: